# contents of Firebase libraries(Android Studio, Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing the Android app using the Android Studio and the Firebase.

When I try to see the contents of Firebase libraries such as 
"android.gms.internal.firebase_auth",searching for the methond named "isEmailVerified", the name of variable and methods seemed encrypted like "zza","zzb" etc.

Any solutions to fix this?

Comment: What you described is expected. What's the problem that you're asking for a solution for?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Auth SDK is currently minimized and obfuscated with Proguard.  This means that the names of private symbols will be mangled like you're seeing now.  There's no "fix" for this, as it is not broken.  It's working as expected.

Some (but not all) of the Firebase SDKs are [open source on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk) if you want to see the original source.  Firebase Auth is currently no open source.